# Create a table that has a number of columns based on a passed in parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

My user wants a report that will accept as a parameter a series of earnings codes and they want the report to display the data with those codes as column headers and their corresponding amounts per row beneath them. I need to do this using SQL Server and Crystal Reports. I'm not sure there is a way to go about this but since I'm relatively new to SQL I haven't been able to figure it out on my own. All record selection is currently done in a stored procedure.

If you need a visual:

```
Employee     ECode1     ECode2     ECode3     ECode4
Bob          $1234      $12        $0         $200
Jane         $1234      $33        $20        $100
```

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I was looking for. Thanks Gordon!

Comment: Another approach would be to simply create a cross tab report in Crystal Reports. It will pivot your data for you with a much simpler sql query:

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=181